# JFrame calls another client JFrame to comunicate with a server

Tags: java

I have built a small program in java to fetch an IP adress from a database then calls a new JFrame (client) to send request to the server. My problem is when I run the server (JFrame) and the client (JFrame also). Separately they work perfectly, but when I call the client from another JFrame which contain a Jtable with data, by clicking on the button, the client JFrame appears but accept to send just one message, and can't receive the sever response unless I close the server. Can anyone help me?

This my code:

The client:

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Machine;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author Win
 */
public class Clio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Clio
     */
    public String adresse = "192.168.10.139";

    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream dun;
    static DataOutputStream dout;
    public Clio() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        msg_area = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        msg_text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        msg_send = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        msg_area.setColumns(20);
        msg_area.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(msg_area);

        msg_text.setText("jTextField1");

        msg_send.setText("Send Trans");
        msg_send.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                msg_sendActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Refresh Connection");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 304, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(msg_text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 252, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(msg_send, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 207, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(msg_text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(msg_send)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void msg_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         try {
        String msgout = "";
        msgout = msg_text.getText().trim();
        dout.writeUTF(msgout);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Clio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Clio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Clio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Clio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Clio().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        try{
          s = new Socket("localhost", 80);
          dun = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
          dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
          String msgin = "";

          while(!msgin.equals("Exit")){
              msgin = dun.readUTF();
              msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n serveur :\t"+msgin); 
          }
         }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea msg_area;
    private javax.swing.JButton msg_send;
    private javax.swing.JTextField msg_text;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The server:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Machine;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Win
 */
public class Serveur extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Interface
     */
    static ServerSocket ss;
    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream dun;
    static DataOutputStream dout;

    public Serveur() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        msg_area = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        msg_text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        msg_send = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        msg_area.setColumns(20);
        msg_area.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(msg_area);

        msg_text.setText("jTextField1");

        msg_send.setText("jButton1");
        msg_send.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                msg_sendActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 336, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(msg_text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(msg_send)))
                .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(msg_text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(msg_send))
                .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void msg_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
        String msgout = "";
        msgout = msg_text.getText().trim();
        dout.writeUTF(msgout);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Serveur.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Serveur.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Serveur.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Serveur.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Serveur().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        String msgin = "";
        try{
         ss = new ServerSocket(80); 
         s = ss.accept();
         dun = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
         dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
         while(!msgin.equals("Exit")){
             msgin = dun.readUTF();
             msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n"+msgin);
         }
        }catch(Exception e){}

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea msg_area;
    private javax.swing.JButton msg_send;
    private javax.swing.JTextField msg_text;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

the table JFrame which will call the client JFrame

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Java;

import Machine.Clio;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Win
 */
public class Call_Transfo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Call_Transfo
     */
    public Call_Transfo() {
        initComponents();
        Show_Users_In_Jtable();

    }
    public void Clio(){
         Socket s= new Socket();
     DataInputStream dun;
     DataOutputStream dout;
     String msgout = "";
     String msgin = "";
     try{
          s = new Socket("localhost", 80);
          dun = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
          dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); 
          msgout = jTextField2.getText().trim();
          dout.writeUTF(msgout);
          msgin = dun.readUTF();
          jTextField3.setText(jTextField3.getText().trim()+"\n serveur :\t"+msgin);

     }catch(Exception e){}
    }
public Connection getConnection(){
       Connection con;
       String ruta ="C:\\Users\\Win\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Newapp\\test.sqlite";
       try{
           Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ruta);
           return con;
       }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); return null;}
    }

public ArrayList<User> getusersList(){
        ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        String query = "Select * from users ";
        Statement st; 
        ResultSet rs;
        try{
          st = connection.createStatement();
          rs = st.executeQuery(query);
          User user;
         while(rs.next()){
             user = new User(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("nom"), rs.getString("région"),rs.getString("adresse"));
             usersList.add(user);
         }  
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return usersList;
    }

    public void Show_Users_In_Jtable(){
        ArrayList<User> list = getusersList();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        Object [] row = new Object[4];
        for(int i =0; i<list.size();i++){
          row[0] = list.get(i).getNom();
          row[1] = list.get(i).getRégion();
          row[2] = list.get(i).getAdresse();
          model.addRow(row);
        }
    }
     // Executer le SQL Query
    public void executeSQLQuery(String query, String message){
        Connection con = getConnection();
        Statement st;
        try{
           st = con.createStatement(); 
           if((st.executeUpdate(query)) == 1){
               // Refresh jtable Data
               DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
               model.setRowCount(0);
               Show_Users_In_Jtable();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+ message + " Successefuly");
            }
           else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data not "+message); 
           }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Kalinga", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Java/wifi-icon (1).png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Appeler");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 130, 120, 30));

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jTextField1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 70, 120, 30));
        jPanel1.add(jTextField3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 160, 210, 80));

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jTextField2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 100, 120, 30));

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Transfo", "Région", "Adresse"
            }
        ));
        jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTable1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jTable1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTable1KeyPressed(evt);
            }
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTable1KeyReleased(evt);
            }
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTable1KeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jPanel1.add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 70, 330, 90));

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Java/Neiige.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, -1, -1));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        int i = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
        jTextField1.setText(model.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
        jTextField2.setText(model.getValueAt(i,2).toString());
    }                                    

    private void jTable1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   

    }                                  

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTable1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                

    private void jTable1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
          int i = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
        jTextField1.setText(model.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
        jTextField2.setText(model.getValueAt(i,2).toString());}
                if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
          int i = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
        jTextField1.setText(model.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
        jTextField2.setText(model.getValueAt(i,2).toString());}
    }                                   

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     Clio Cl = new Clio();
     Cl.validate();
     Cl.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Call_Transfo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Call_Transfo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Call_Transfo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Call_Transfo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Call_Transfo().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Source code too long. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry,my problem is in the third code , exactely here when I click to call for the client Jframe it appears but doesn't work properly

Comment: private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     Clio Cl = new Clio();
     Cl.validate();
     Cl.setVisible(true);
    }